# Get index of ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems for specific Tag without foreach loop

Tags: c#, indexof

Is there a way to get index of `ToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems` for an item in the collection having a specific tag, without using foreach loop?

I am currently doing it like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 myForm2 = new Form2();
    myForm2.OnTemplateUpdated += new Form2.TemplateUpdatedHandler(myForm2_OnTemplateUpdated);
    myForm2.Show();
}

void myForm2_OnTemplateUpdated(Form s, TemplateUpdatedEvent e)
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem myMenuItem in templatesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems)
    {
        if ((string)myMenuItem.Tag == e.TemplateId)
        {
            templatesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems[index].Text = e.NewName;
            break;
        }
        index++;
    }
}
```

I know `templatesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems` has a `IndexOf()` method, but I am not having any luck trying to use it like this:

```
int menuItemIndex = templatesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems
    .IndexOf(new ToolStripMenuItem() { Tag = e.TemplateId });
```

The `menuItemIndex` is always `-1`... perhaps I'm using the method incorrectly?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are using IndexOf incorrectly as you are trying to get the index of a newly created item.

Comment: hence the question here, how do you get the `IndexOf` correctly =[

Comment: IndexOf expects the actual ToolStripMenuItem itself so, the answer is no, you can't. Either do what you are doing or use First and Where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign names to the items in the`DropDownItems`, that corresponds with their `Tag`s. For instance:

```
templatesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Item text") { Tag = 1, Name = "item1" });
```

Thus you can get the desired item as follows:

```
templatesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems["item" + e.TemplateId].Text = e.NewName;
```